# Load a web view after opening a notification alert?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, push-notification, uialertview, redirect

I made a RSS app, it works perfectly, I also added Push Notification Support, everything is good so far, am passing a title, alert, and a url as an extra field.

When my notification arrives, I show my alert, and you have 2 options "Thanx | Open"

All I want to do now is, when you click open from this alert, I need to redirect my user to a view that has a UIwebview and load the url I passed along with the notification.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
// here is my app delegate 

    -(void)onReceivePushNotification:(NSDictionary *) pushDict andPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload {
        [payload valueForKey:@"title"];
        UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Alert !" message:[pushDict valueForKey:@"alert"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks !" otherButtonTitles: @"Open",nil];

        NSLog(@"message was : %@", [pushDict valueForKey:@"alert"]);
        NSLog(@"url was : %@", [payload valueForKey:@"url"]);
        [message show];
    }
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
        if([title isEqualToString:@"Open"]) {
            [[Pushbots getInstance] OpenedNotification];
            // Decrease Badge count by 1
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber -1];
            // Decrease badge count on the server
            [[Pushbots getInstance] decreaseBadgeCountBy:@"1"];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateRoot" object:nil];
        } else {
            // set Badge to 0
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
            // reset badge on the server
            [[Pushbots getInstance] resetBadgeCount];
        }
    }
```

My detail view is called : "APPDetailViewController", with a web view called "webView"

Please help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance of APPDetailViewController in your clickedButtonAtIndex method and present it. If you have tabs, you can switch to that tab, and then have a method to pass the url to so that it opens that page.

Comment: the web view isn't in a tab, it's connected to a uitableview through a navigationViewController that is embedded in a tabviewController along with 3 other views , any solutions !

Comment: I am confused. You have a view controller with a table view, you tap a cell, this goes to a new view controller with the web view?

Comment: yes, and that table view is using navigation view controller for push segue , 
here is the anatomy of my app, it's using UITabBarViewController to hold 4 tabs
1st tab > "news" UINavagationViewController > UITableView > click a cell > UIViewController > load WebView
2nd tab > static youtube webview
3rd tab > Contact Us
4th tab > About the app